# Remove a particular field for all documents in a collection using MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How to Remove a particular value for all records in the collection using aggregation :

Have a collection with data :

```
[
 {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcw",
    name: "lucas",
    occupation: "scientist",
    present_working:true,
    age: 55,
    location: "texas",
    date:2019-11-25T10:49:36.534+00:00

  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcx",
    name: "mark",
    occupation: "scientist",
    age: 45,
    present_working:true,
    location: "texas",
    date:null
  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcq",
    name: "cooper",
    occupation: "physicist",
    age: 69,
    location: "texas",
    date:null
  }
]
```

Remove the rows in records for which there is `date:null`. Data need not be removed in the database, it should be only modified in the aggregation pipeline

Expected output after removing only `date:null` :

```
[
 {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcw",
    name: "lucas",
    occupation: "scientist",
    present_working:true,
    age: 55,
    location: "texas",
    date:2019-11-25T10:49:36.534+00:00

  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcx",
    name: "mark",
    occupation: "scientist",
    age: 45,
    present_working:true,
    location: "texas"
  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcq",
    name: "cooper",
    occupation: "physicist",
    age: 69,
    location: "texas"
  }
]
```

MongoDB version: **4.0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/index.html) operator & `$$REMOVE` to do that :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      date: {
        $ifNull: [
          "$date",
          "$$REMOVE"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5s_NvfEj9gB)